# How to save data in a 32 bit binary file in matlab?

Tags: file, matlab, file-io, binary, 32-bit

I have to test some "random numbers" with diehard, generated by a program in MATLAB. Diehard accepts only a 32 bit binary file (single precision), but if I save my data in MATLAB, it is saved in a binary file with double precision (so 2*64 = 128 bit binary file). How can I create a 32 bit binary file in MATLAB, working on a 64 bit system?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read/write data to a binary file in a specific format, you should use the functions [FREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html)/[FWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fwrite.html). For example, this will write 100 random values to a file as 32-bit floats:

```
A = rand(1,100);
fid = fopen('temp.dat','wb');
fwrite(fid,A,'float32');
fclose(fid);
```

For more info about file IO in MATLAB, you can also check out these other related SO posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205735/read-and-write-from-to-a-binary-file-in-matlab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872209/sharing-memory-between-processes-matlab/878327#878327).

Answer (score 3):

Further to gnovice's solution, you may wish to generate the random numbers as 'single', like so:

```
rand(1, 100, 'single')
```

Comment: This is good to remember if you are dealing with very large matrices, since it will take up less space than the default double precision that RAND would use. However, you still have to specify the precision for FWRITE to use. If it isn't specified, FWRITE will default to 'uint8' precision (for some reason, it doesn't just choose the precision of the variable you pass it).