# How to make several scripts share a large matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing memory between processes [matlab]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872209/sharing-memory-between-processes-matlab)

I'm currently working on a problem that involves a `huge dense matrix` (about 3e4*3e4, and the mat file is about 2.3G). I have several different scripts, which correspond to different experimental settings, but this matrix is used in all these scripts. Since these experiments are quite time-consuming, I want to run them in parallel, but I only have a limited amount of memory, so I can't load this matrix to the memory multiple times.

**Question :** Is there a way to run these scripts in parallel but also let them share the same matrix (i.e. load the matrix to the memory only once)?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have parallel computing toolbox?